# Tolerance of 10 mins after and before registered time field

Tags: php, mysql

I know the Title seems really confusing, but it's the closest I can get to what I really need to do...

Let me try to explain, I have a `column` in my `mySQL` table where have fields of *hours* (string), *date of registration* and *access code*.

To redirect to the required page, he needs to fill the `input` of *access code*, when he fill and submit the `form`, a entire `select` is made:

```
$sql = 'SELECT
            agendamentos.data_agendada,
            agendamentos.codigo_acesso,
            horarios.horario
        FROM
            agendamentos
        INNER JOIN horarios ON agendamentos.horario_id = horarios.id
        WHERE
            agendamentos.aluno_codigopessoa = '.$usrs->codigoPessoa.'
            AND agendamentos.codigo_acesso = '.$_POST['acesso_chat'];

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

This returns me if the access code exists, the **hour** that he chooses and the date.

I need to make a comparison with the hour of the result with a new `DateTime()` object, but, I can't let him go through if the **hour** of the result isn't in a period of **10 minutes before and 10 minutes after** the one he selected.

I tried a few codes, and I really can add minutes to the object of `DateTime`, which is what I did, BUT, how do I even do one `if` statement to see if the hour he selected is in the **period of 10 minutes before and 10 minutes after the current time**?

Comment: Does it have to be done with DateTimes? Or can you use the database?

Comment: @bassxzero , the column have a certain hour (e.g: 14:00:00) and it's a string, what I need to do is to determine 10 minutes of tolerance after and before this result, where they can still access from 13:50:00 until 14:10:00

Comment: yeah i get that, but why aren't you using TimeStamps or Times? MySQL has them built in

Comment: @bassxzero, They are setted to TIME right now, but the question still, how can I do a statement to determine this tolerance?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: @bassxzero sorry for the ignorance, but I don't get it, how I'll determine if someone can access a certain website using a select to see between 13:50:00 and 14:10:00 if there's only 14:00:00 registered on the table?

Comment: something like this `select * from some_table where now() between (time_column - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) and (time_column + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either via `PHP` or `MySQL`:

`PHP` version:

```
//given your result is something like this:
$result = array(
    'codigo_acesso' => 'ABCDE',
    'data_agendada' => '2016-10-26',
    'horario'       => '14:00:00'
);


$timestamp = strtotime($result['data_agendada'] . ' ' . $result['horario']);
$now       = mktime();
$diff      = $now - $timestamp;
$tolerance = 10 * 60; //10 minutes

if (abs($diff) <= $tolerance) {
    //grant access
} else {
    //deny access
}
```

and `MySQL` version:

```
$tolerance = 10 * 60; //10 minutes

$sql = "SELECT
            agendamentos.data_agendada,
            agendamentos.codigo_acesso,
            horarios.horario
        FROM
            agendamentos
        INNER JOIN horarios ON agendamentos.horario_id = horarios.id
        WHERE
            agendamentos.aluno_codigopessoa = :codigo_pessoa
            AND agendamentos.codigo_acesso = :acesso_chat
            AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(agendamentos.data_agendada, ' ', horarios.horario), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))) <= " . $tolerance; //

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(
    ':codigo_pessoa' => $usrs->codigoPessoa,
    ':acesso_chat'   => $_POST['acesso_chat']
));
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

if (!empty($result)) {
    //grant access
} else {
    //deny access
}
```

Prefer `MySQL` version.

Comment: I prefer the MySQL version as well

Comment: So it should be something like AND (NOW() - STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(agendamentos.data_agendada, ' ', horarios.horario), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') <= 10
            OR NOW() - STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(agendamentos.data_agendada, ' ', horarios.horario), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= 10) ?

Comment: not 10, 600. The result is in seconds, so you have to transform your 10 minutes in seconds (multiplying by 60). <= if you want to get the result within your timespan, >= otherwhise. You do not need to subtract one from another. ABS() will give you a positive value that you can compare with a positive tolerance. It doesn't care if it's before or after the time scheduled.

Comment: @WaldsonPatricio This query is giving me nothing on result, I tried scheduling one for 16:00:00 and with the <= statement nothing shows up, 10 minutes before and 10 after still doesn't show

Comment: <= will show up only between 15:50:00 and 16:10:00. If you want to show only when not in this interval use > instead.

Comment: I know, I need the "<=" but still, he doesn't show up nothing, even if the hour is right

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT NOW() from dual`? Maybe your database is within a different timezone (daylight saving time, for example).

Comment: What is the data type of `data_agendada` field? Give me a sample of data stored in there.

Comment: It's TIME , should it be TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Should be DATE for `data_agendada` and TIME for `horario`.

Comment: It is DATE for data_agendada and TIME for horario... Still nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126760/discussion-between-waldson-patricio-and-felipe-s-bueno).